# jQuery Time ago with php time stamp

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using jQuery timeago to display comment posted time on my site. Problem is that it's showing totally different (10 hours different) time then it supposed to be. in my local server it works fine.

timeago: http://timeago.yarp.com/

```
/**
 * Timeago is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to support automatically
 * updating fuzzy timestamps (e.g. "4 minutes ago" or "about 1 day ago").
 *
 * @name timeago
 * @version 0.11.1
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.3+
 * @author Ryan McGeary
 * @license MIT License - http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * For usage and examples, visit:
 * http://timeago.yarp.com/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2008-2011, Ryan McGeary (ryanonjavascript -[at]- mcgeary [*dot*] org)
 */
(function($) {
  $.timeago = function(timestamp) {
    if (timestamp instanceof Date) {
      return inWords(timestamp);
    } else if (typeof timestamp === "string") {
      return inWords($.timeago.parse(timestamp));
    } else {
      return inWords($.timeago.datetime(timestamp));
    }
  };
  var $t = $.timeago;

  $.extend($.timeago, {
    settings: {
      refreshMillis: 60000,
      allowFuture: false,
      strings: {
        prefixAgo: null,
        prefixFromNow: null,
        suffixAgo: "ago",
        suffixFromNow: "from now",
        seconds: "less than a minute",
        minute: "about a minute",
        minutes: "%d minutes",
        hour: "about an hour",
        hours: "about %d hours",
        day: "a day",
        days: "%d days",
        month: "about a month",
        months: "%d months",
        year: "about a year",
        years: "%d years",
        wordSeparator: " ",
        numbers: []
      }
    },
    inWords: function(distanceMillis) {
      var $l = this.settings.strings;
      var prefix = $l.prefixAgo;
      var suffix = $l.suffixAgo;
      if (this.settings.allowFuture) {
        if (distanceMillis < 0) {
          prefix = $l.prefixFromNow;
          suffix = $l.suffixFromNow;
        }
      }

      var seconds = Math.abs(distanceMillis) / 1000;
      var minutes = seconds / 60;
      var hours = minutes / 60;
      var days = hours / 24;
      var years = days / 365;

      function substitute(stringOrFunction, number) {
        var string = $.isFunction(stringOrFunction) ? stringOrFunction(number, distanceMillis) : stringOrFunction;
        var value = ($l.numbers && $l.numbers[number]) || number;
        return string.replace(/%d/i, value);
      }

      var words = seconds < 45 && substitute($l.seconds, Math.round(seconds)) ||
        seconds < 90 && substitute($l.minute, 1) ||
        minutes < 45 && substitute($l.minutes, Math.round(minutes)) ||
        minutes < 90 && substitute($l.hour, 1) ||
        hours < 24 && substitute($l.hours, Math.round(hours)) ||
        hours < 42 && substitute($l.day, 1) ||
        days < 30 && substitute($l.days, Math.round(days)) ||
        days < 45 && substitute($l.month, 1) ||
        days < 365 && substitute($l.months, Math.round(days / 30)) ||
        years < 1.5 && substitute($l.year, 1) ||
        substitute($l.years, Math.round(years));

      var separator = $l.wordSeparator === undefined ?  " " : $l.wordSeparator;
      return $.trim([prefix, words, suffix].join(separator));
    },
    parse: function(iso8601) {
      var s = $.trim(iso8601);
      s = s.replace(/\.\d\d\d+/,""); // remove milliseconds
      s = s.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/");
      s = s.replace(/T/," ").replace(/Z/," UTC");
      s = s.replace(/([\+\-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/," $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
      return new Date(s);
    },
    datetime: function(elem) {
      // jQuery's `is()` doesn't play well with HTML5 in IE
      var isTime = $(elem).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() === "time"; // $(elem).is("time");
      var iso8601 = isTime ? $(elem).attr("datetime") : $(elem).attr("title");
      return $t.parse(iso8601);
    }
  });

  $.fn.timeago = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.each(refresh);

    var $s = $t.settings;
    if ($s.refreshMillis > 0) {
      setInterval(function() { self.each(refresh); }, $s.refreshMillis);
    }
    return self;
  };

  function refresh() {
    var data = prepareData(this);
    if (!isNaN(data.datetime)) {
      $(this).text(inWords(data.datetime));
    }
    return this;
  }

  function prepareData(element) {
    element = $(element);
    if (!element.data("timeago")) {
      element.data("timeago", { datetime: $t.datetime(element) });
      var text = $.trim(element.text());
      if (text.length > 0) {
        element.attr("title", text);
      }
    }
    return element.data("timeago");
  }

  function inWords(date) {
    return $t.inWords(distance(date));
  }

  function distance(date) {
    return (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime());
  }

  // fix for IE6 suckage
  document.createElement("abbr");
  document.createElement("time");
}(jQuery));
```

im saving date and time to my database using `date('r',time());`

im displaying the time using `<abbr class="timeago" title="2012-05-24 02:18:59"></abbr>`

Comment: If this is dynamic then plz check your server timestamp, that might be diff.

Answer (score 0):

Its zone problem . Its better to use UTC time in server . u can get zone by using following javascript in your page .

```
var d = new Date(); var zone = -d.getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

Comment: do you mean use this on the timeago jquery or use it in saving the timestamp in the database? thanks

Comment: d.getTimezoneOffset() return both positive/negative minutes; so the minus isnt wrong here?